# Set DatePicker to Today using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datepicker

I have the following [`DatePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx) control in my project:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="startDate" SelectedDate="2013-04-03"></DatePicker>
```

**QUESTION:**
Is it possible to set the [`DatePicker.SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate.aspx) using only XAML?

I know this can be achieved using code-behind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this...

Add this to xaml refs:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then write this:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
```

Comment: I had to use *system:* not *sys:*. Any idea why?

Comment: @KonradViltersten The name is irrelevant, perhaps you already had something declared as sys

Comment: Ah, **now** I see that part with *xmlns:sys* in your post relating to *xmlns:system* in my code.